# Choose one of three identical swing components using AssertJ

Tags: java, swing, assertj

I use AssertJ to test my swing application. When I try to use this code

```
frame.button(JButtonMatcher.withText("text").andShowing()).click();`
```

I get this error:

```
Found more than one component using matcher org.assertj.swing.core.matcher.JButtonMatcher[
    name=<Any>, text='text', requireShowing=true]
```

Because I have three identical components in one form and I can't change names or titles of this one. Any advice?

Comment: *"Any advice?"* Don't build confusing GUIs. How is the user supposed to determine which of three identical buttons to activate?

Comment: In the panel we have 3 another panels which contains any elements, and one of this element is this button which has the same names

Comment: Way to vague this up! I am no closer to determining the answer to my question than I was before.

Comment: So, I'm agree with You, but I have code, which I may test, but don't edit. The best way is change method of initialize that buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and easiest solution to your problem would be if you could give the buttons distinct names.

Remember: the `name` of a component is distinct from the `text` it displays! Your buttons could all be showing "text" to the users, but still have names like "button1", "button2", "button3".

In this case you could write

```
frame.button(JButtonMatcher.withName("button1").withText("text").andShowing()).click();
```

---

The next possibility would be to give the panels containing the buttons distinct names, for example "panel1", "panel2", "panel3".

If you can implement this you could write

```
frame.panel("panel1").button(JButtonMatcher.withText("text").andShowing()).click();
```

---

The last and worst possibility would be to write your own `GenericTypeMatcher` / `NamedComponentMatcherTemplate` that returns only the `n`th button matching the given text.

**PLEASE BEWARE**:

- this is a desparate measure if all other approaches fail
- This will lead to fragile tests
- You don't want to do this unless there is absolute no other way!

With these warnings in place, this is code:

```
public class MyJButtonMatcher extends NamedComponentMatcherTemplate<JButton> {

    private String text;
    private int index;

    public MyJButtonMatcher(String text, int index) {
        super(JButton.class);
        this.text = text;
        this.index = index;
        requireShowing(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isMatching(JButton button) {
        if (isNameMatching(button.getName()) && arePropertyValuesMatching(text, button.getText())) {
            return index-- == 0;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```